# Does 1-ethylidene-2-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclobutane show geometrical isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

[image: (1E)-1-ethylidene-2-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclobutane]

I think it should be yes, but my book says no.
I think the two geometrical isomers are

**Z-isomer**

[image: (1Z)-1-ethylidene-2-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclobutane]

**E-isomer**

[image: (1E)-1-ethylidene-2-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclobutane]

Comment: Which book? Please state the source properly.

Comment: The book is wrong unless one of the two does not exist. For the (hypothetical? ) structures you are right.

Comment: Well, there would be sever sterical clash for Z, so it's practically non-existant.

Answer (score 1):

The two isomers are distinct substances, differing only in the orientation of a double bond, so they must be geometrical isomers. However, as a practical matter, they may interconvert under mild conditions and/or one may be much less stable than the other.